# Wordpress Multisite on Local vhost won't load domain-based sites

Tags: apache-http-server

I've set up a Wordpress Multisite on my Local Mac, and also set up an Apache Virtual Host (e.g http://maindomain.dev) to point to the directory. The Multisite used to be a Directory Based install (e.g http://maindomain.dev/subdirectory), but I read that you convert it to a Domain Based install by changing the value of 
    define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
to
    define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
and then updating the .htaccess file. I did all of this, and Wordpress appears to work fine. However, when I create a new site and try to access it (e.g http://subdomain.maindomain.dev), the browser (Chrome) just hangs for a while and then times out.

I read somewhere that a Wordpress Multisite domain-based install can't be installed locally, but it should work with an Apache Virtual Host, but I can't remember the URL for that page.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: does subdomain.maindomain.dev resolve to localhost?

Comment: No, it just times out and gives Chrome's 'This Webpage is not Available' message: http://cl.ly/Qds8

Comment: try adding the subdomains to your /etc/hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1, or if you have something intercepting .dev domains, set that up to return 127.0.0.1 for the wildcard.  By resolve I meant via dns / local lookup. not chrome (trying to see if issue is DNS based, or apache based)

Comment: I added subdomain.maindomain.dev    127.0.0.1 to my hosts file and it now resolves to 127.0.0.1, very quickly. What do I do now?

Comment: assuming that your apache virtual hosts listens on 127.0.0.1 and can deal with the hostname it should work.

Comment: Just posted my solution below, @Doon - thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this working, eventually. Steps to get it working:

Add the subdomain.maindomain.dev to your `hosts` file (on a Mac, it's located at `/etc/hosts`), next to your 127.0.0.1 localhost maindomain.dev. Your hosts file should look like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost maindomain.dev subdomain.maindomain.dev subdomain2.maindomain.dev
```

Of course, you can have other entries in your hosts file as well. But this needs to be located somewhere (preferably at the top). Also, putting all your entries for 127.0.0.1 radically speeds up loading time for vhosts.

Next, open `httpd-vhosts.conf` (located at `/etc/apache2/extra`) and where your Virtual Host has been defined, add `ServerAlias *.maindomain.dev`. The Virtual Host declaration should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/folder"
    ServerName maindomain.dev
    ServerAlias *.maindomain.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

restart Apache using `apachectl -k restart` (you may need to add `sudo` before this command).

The only problem with this is that each time you create a new Site using Wordpress Multisite, you have to define it in your `hosts` file.

I hope this helps anyone who has the same or similar problem to me! :)

Comment: you can also look into things like dns proxies on the local machine (things like pow.cx do this) so  you don't need to modify the hosts file all the time, but alas hosts files don't support wildcards (*.dev) but editing the host file for testing isn't too horrible