# Wordpress Multisite Localhost with SSL (for testing purposes only)

Tags: localhost, openssl, wordpress, subdomain

I have followed through the instructions as referenced in [Wordpress Multisite on Local vhost won't load domain-based sites](https://superuser.com/questions/628234/wordpress-multisite-on-local-vhost-wont-load-domain-based-sites).

Background Info

1. I have installed WAMP stack manually (not using XAMPP or WampServer)
2. The stack are working properly.
3. All installation folders were put under \apache\htdocs
4. WordPress, Drupal 7 etc have been installed successfully
5. I have created 127.0.0.1 localhost in \system32\drivers\etc\hosts
6. I have added 127.0.0.1:443 localhost perfectinduction operations.perfectinduction
7. Configured httpd.conf to remove comment include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
8. Added the following in \apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts-conf:

DocumentRoot "C:/vhosts/perfectinduction"
ServerName operations.perfectinduction
ServerAlias *. perfectinduction
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile C:/vhosts/perfectinduction/perfectinduction.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/vhosts/perfectinduction/perfectinduction.key

9. I have added a new site whose fqdn is https://operations.perfectinduction.
10. Network admin showed the site is set up.
11. Click "visit site" gives a timed out error message.

I am at a loss as how to get local (secure though through self-signed cert) WordPress multisites to work.

I appreciate any help. Thanking all in advance.

Comment: Any news on that matter?

Comment: @fernando. Unfortunately no. BTW, I have moved to Drupal 8, instead. Thanks